# Add cluster to an existing table in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, alter-table, database-cluster

Is it possible to add cluster to an existing table? For example...
I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(  
t_id number PRIMARY KEY,  
t_name varchar2(50));
```

Cluster:

```
CREATE CLUSTER my_cluster
(c_id NUMBER) SIZE 100;
```

Is there a command like: `ALTER TABLE t_name ADD CLUSTER my_cluster(t_id);`  or something like that?
Because I want table to look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(  
t_id number PRIMARY KEY,  
t_name varchar2(50))  
CLUSTER my_cluster(t_id);
```

And dropping all connected tables isn't really what I want to do.
Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to build a cluster.  I've been working with Oracle for almost twenty years and I've never come across a case for them.

Comment: Thing is I don't want to build a cluster, I just have to for my university task.

Comment: it is sad that universities are wasting their students' time with things that they will *never* use in real life.  Good luck with your studies :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You really need to understand what a cluster really is. From [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10743/intro.htm#sthref69):

> "Clusters are groups of one or more tables *physically stored
>   together* because they share common columns and are often used
>   together. Because related rows are physically stored together, disk
>   access time improves."  (emphasis mine)

The point being, the tables in a cluster are **co-located**.  This is a physical arrangement. So, for the database to cluster existing tables we must drop and re-create them.

It is possible to minimise the downtime by building the clustered table under a different name. You will need to keep the data in synch with the live table until you are ready to swap.  You will need to restrict access to the database while you do this, to prevent data loss. Then you rename the old  table, rename the clustered table with the proper name, run the necessary grants and recompile invalid procedures, synonyms, etc.

Comment: I just asked. I don't know how I wanted to achieve it, I am a newb to databases. Ok then I guess I will drop and recreate or recreate copies with different name.

Comment: need appropriate answer

Comment: It is impossible for me to recreate a table for cluster. I need a solution for existing Table (any how).

Comment: Why do you need to cluster your table?  If the anticipated benefits are so great that they justify an outage then you should go ahead. Otherwise you should consider whether clustering is the solution you need.

Comment: @nislam - I have expanded my answer with an approach which minimises downtime. But there is no solution which offers zero outage.